# I need make this on python any ideas

Tags: php, python, xml

i need do this on python any help, this code check modem status from xml file and activates a service if is not OK

XML Example

```
<SMSCStatus>
        <Name>HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem</Name>
        <Status>ERROR</Status>
        <StatusDetail>
                Modem Failure -- Unable to access modem, ensure that it is powered on and passes diagnostic tests.
        </StatusDetail>
        <MessagesToday>0</MessagesToday>
        <MessagesLast7Days>0</MessagesLast7Days>
        <MessagesLast30Days>0</MessagesLast30Days>
</SMSCStatus>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile");
$status1 = $xml->SMSCStatus->Status;

if ($status1 == "OK")
        {
        $fp = fopen("status.txt", "w");
        fwrite($fp, "2");
        fclose($fp);
        }
  else
        {
        $statusr = json_encode(array(
                'server' => 'TOO FAIL'
        ));
        echo exec('net start "NowSMS"');
        }

?>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: i just need an example. how to do this 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile");
    $status1 = $xml->SMSCStatus->Status; with python no write my code

Comment: Take a look at [the modules available in the standard library for parsing XML](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/markup.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/easiest-way-to-parse-xml-in-python) as a replacement for `simplexml_load_file` and the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for exec.